# How to filter a multiple array bye value[0] of each line?

Tags: javascript

I would like to filter a multiple array in JS by the value[0] of each line. In my next array, there are several "visiteur", "paris", "monaco" and I want to have juste one of each. Any idea ?

My array :

0: ['firstname', 'id']

1: ['FootContact Team', '1']

2: ['Cergy Pontoise Football Club', '2']

3: ['visiteur', '42']

4: ['visiteur', '43']

5: ['visiteur', '44']

6: ['monaco', '45']

7: ['monaco', '46']

8: ['paris', '47']

9: ['paris', '48']

I expect this :

0: ['firstname', 'id']

1: ['FootContact Team', '1']

2: ['Cergy Pontoise Football Club', '2']

3: ['visiteur', '42']

6: ['monaco', '45']

8: ['paris', '47']

Comment: You should add your array and expected result also...

Comment: I don't understand ?

Comment: What should be the result?

Comment: Okay I added my expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let listOfUsers = [['toto', 1], ['titi', 2],['titi', 5], ['visiteur',3], ['visiteur', 4]];
let filtered = {};
listOfUsers = listOfUsers.filter((user) => {
    let name = user[0];
    if (!filtered[name]) {
        // set flag and return true since it's the first happening
        return filtered[name] = true;
    }
});
console.log(listOfUsers);
```

Comment: Thanks Marxys to your answerd but it filters just 'visiteur' right ? I forgot to specify that there are other lines like ['monaco' : '10'] ['monaco' : '11'] ['paris' : '12'] ['paris' : '13']... There are not just 'visiteur' to filter. I'm gonna edit my question

Comment: @LauraBossy I have fixed following your specs

Comment: Yeah that's it, it works ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Generically speaking, you want to keep an element in your array if it did not show up beforehand.

- `input.filter((element, index, array) => ...)` uses the additional filter arguments
- `array.slice(0, index)` contains the array elements smaller than the current index
- `some(element2 => (element[0] === element2[0]))` returns true if at least one prior element is identical wrt. to the first element

```js
let input = [
    ['firstname', 'id'],
    ['FootContact Team', '1'],
    ['Cergy Pontoise Football Club', '2'],
    ['visiteur', '42'],
    ['visiteur', '43'],
    ['visiteur', '44'],
    ['monaco', '45'],
    ['monaco', '46'],
    ['paris', '47'],
    ['paris', '48'],
]

let expectedOutput = [
    ['firstname', 'id'],
    ['FootContact Team', '1'],
    ['Cergy Pontoise Football Club', '2'],
    ['visiteur', '42'],
    ['monaco', '45'],
    ['paris', '47'],
]

let actualOutput = input.filter((element, index, array) =>  !array.slice(0, index).some(element2 => (element[0] === element2[0])))

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(actualOutput) 
  ===
  JSON.stringify(expectedOutput)
)
```

Comment: Okay thanks I'm gonna try this too